# From factory to $scope . What is the right way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I would like to know which is the correct way to initialize a variable with the data of a factory. Currently I do it this way, but does not convince me . I'm wrong? I 'm using Angular.

```
$scope.result = [];
factoryCities.then(function(data){
    $scope.result = data;    
});
```

Comment: what does "does not convince me" mean?  this looks like valid code, are you not seeing the output you expect?

Comment: I am not convinced that the view starts with an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factory (singleton) is a service that aims to provide variables and/or methods.

in your controller:

...

```
MyFactory.var1 = $scope.var1;
$scope.resultOfSomethingDone = MyFactory.doSomething();
```

And if implements promises (asynchronously, return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.) :

```
MyFactory.getData().then(function(data){
    $scope.dataResult = data;    
});
```